# How does cavity resonance produce EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, frequency, resonance

My understanding is it acts like a capacitor and inductor in a loop. The capacitor releases stored energy which is absorbed by the inductor through a magnetic field which then returns it to the capacitor, leading to a resonation. This resonation produces an EM wave.

1) How does resonation between electric and magnetic fields produce EM waves?

2) How does the control of the dimensions of the device control the frequency of the wave?

3) What is the mathematical relationship between the resonance frequency and the EM wave frequency?

4) how does the permitivity and Q-factor relate to the control the resonance?

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are a property of the vacuum. If we surround the vacuum with a conducting cavity, we restrict the boundary conditions on electromagnetic waves, but we aren't actually "producing" them.

Comment: _"EM waves are produced due to disturbances in electric and magnetic fields"_. Read this: [Electrical resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resonance)

Comment: @CuriousOne vacuum is *the* property of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @hyportnex: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. My collection of magnets and rf amplifiers have, as of yet, failed to produce any additional space in my house. ;-)